# I want to save my pdf file in automatically generated folder. In this code pdf file is generated outside of folder

Tags: vba, ms-access, mkdir

i want to save my pdf file in the folder(MkDir).which is generated outside of the folder.
please tell me how I can save the pdf file in Dir.

```
'20220630
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim strSQL As String
 
    'strFilter = "¿‹“ú >= #" & Format(Date,"yyyy/mm") & "/01# AND " & _
    '            "¿‹“ú < #" & Format(DateAdd("m",1,Date),"yyyy/mm") & "/01"
 
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT KJU250 FROM Q_¿‹ ", _
                              dbOpenForwardOnly, dbReadOnly)
     
    Set qd = db.QueryDefs("Q_¿‹")
    strSQL = Replace(qd.SQL, ";", "")
    
      filepath = "C:\Lƒf[ƒ^\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & rs!KJU250
     
       If Dir(filepath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
       MkDir filepath

       End If
      
       
     Do Until rs.EOF
        *'i want to save that pdf file in the MkDir directory which is autogenerated folder*

        qd.SQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strFilter & "  AND SEIKYUCD=" & rs!SEIKYUCD
        
       qd.SQL = strSQL & " WHERE KJU250=" & rs!KJU250
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "R_¿‹‘", acFormatPDF, _
            \Lƒf[ƒ^\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & rs!KJU250 & ".pdf"
      
            
        rs.MoveNext
        
    Loop
  
 
    qd.SQL = strSQL & ";"
    rs.Close
'20220630
```

Comment: Please include code as text, not as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

How about using your `filepath`:

```vb
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "R_¿‹‘", acFormatPDF, filepath & ".pdf"
```